# How can I get all objects of a model and it's fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Product Model and I want to be able to count all it's objects in a method so I can render the total number in a template, same for each category but I can only do that with the number_of_likes method.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    ...

class Product(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TYPE, default='Physical')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='like')
    ...

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def number_of_products(self):
        return self.Products.objects.all.count()

    def number_of_products_for_category(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(category_id=self.category_id).count()


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title) + ' from ' + str(self.author)



        <div>
            <h3>All products ({{ number_of_products }})</h3>
            {% for category in categories %}
                <p>{{ category.name }} (q)</p>
                {{ number_of_products_for_category }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

The number_of_products and number_of_products_for_category are the methods that aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with:

```
def number_of_products_for_category(self):
    return Product.objects.filter(category_id=self.category_id).count()
```

But if you use this for *all* categories, you can [**`.annotate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count

categories = Category.objects.annotate(num_products=Count('product'))
```

and render with:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <p>{{ category.name }} ({{ category.num_products }})</p>
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: How should I use it in the template?